# Não estou conseguindo ordenar as notas com o uso de struct

Tags: c, classificação

Queria ordenar as notas dos alunos, só que não estou conseguindo fazer por que na hora de receber as notas estou utilizando o índice j, acho que isso é o problema só que não sei como resolver.

```
 #include<stdio.h>
 #include<stdlib.h>

double ordena(double *a, double *b);

struct notas
{
  double notas[3];
  char nome[100];
};


int main(void)
{
  int i, j;
  struct notas aluno[2];
  for(i = 0; i < 2; i++)
  {
    printf("Informe os nomes dos alunos :");
    scanf("%s", aluno[i].nome);
    system("cls");
    for(j = 0; j < 3; j++)
    {
        printf("Informe as notas do aluno %d:", j + 1);
        scanf("%lf", &aluno[i].notas[j]);
        system("cls");
    }
    system("cls");
   }
   for(i = 0; i < 2; i++)
   {
      for(j = i + 1; j < 3; j++)
       {
        ordena(&aluno[i].notas[j], &aluno[j].notas[j]);
       }
   }
   for(i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
      printf("Nome dos alunos %s:", aluno[i].nome);
       for(i = 0; i < 3; i++)
       {
        printf("%.2lf\n", aluno[i].notas[j]);
       }
  }
  system("pause");
  return 0;
}

double ordena(double *a, double *b)
{
  double o;
  if(*a > *b)
  {
    o = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = o;
  }
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: A função que tem chamada `ordena` na verdade não ordena e simplesmente troca valores de variaveis, o que se costuma chamar de `swap`. Comece por ler sobre bubblesort por exemplo, que é dos algoritmos mais simples de ordenação.

Answer (score 0):

A função ordena que você escreveu não faz nada mais do que a troca dos elementos. O certo seria fazer a ordenação dentro da função. Ex:

```
void ordena(double vet[]) {
    int i, j;
    double aux;

    for (i = 1; i < 3; i++) {
        aux = vet[i];

        for (j = i - 1; (j >= 0) && (aux < vet[j]); j--) {
            vet[j + 1] = vet[j];
        }

        vet[j+1] = aux;
    }
}
```

Para ordenar é só chamar:

```
for(i = 0; i < 2; i++){
   ordena(alunos[i].notas);
}
```

E na hora de fazer a exibição dos valores você está usando a váriavel 'i' em 2 laços `for` diferentes no mesmo escopo. O certo seria assim:

```
for(i = 0; i < 2; i++){
     printf("Nome dos alunos %s:", alunos[i].nome);
     for(j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
        printf("%.2lf\n", alunos[i].notas[j]);
     }
}
```

E só para terminar evite sempre declarar variáveis com o mesmo nome da struct em que ela pertence, se não o seu código ficará difícil de ler. O que eu sugiro é que ao invés de 'notas', declares a struct com o nome 'Alunos' já que ela guarda informações sobre os alunos.